# Solaris 10 OK PROMPT - CDROM situation

Tags: solaris, optical-media

This is not an emergency, but I would like to save a trip to the datacentre during the weekend.

It turns out that I need to reinstall Solaris 10 on a server, but the drive seems to be open/ejected. Is there a way from the OK prompt to close the drive? Maybe I'm talking nonsense, but I'm just wondering if there could be something that could do the trick!

Answer (score 5):

Here are some things you could try:

- `probe-scsi-all` at the ok prompt. It maybe that it sends the START UNIT command to the drive. If not then try `setenv auto-boot? false` and `reset-all`. This should bring you back to the ok prompt (hopefully the tray is now closed and you can `boot cdrom` The crux of it is getting the SCSI "START UNIT" command to the drive. If it's one of those drives that are not motorized then you need to go and do fingerpoken at the site.
- If you are lucky there is a jumpstart server on your network and you can use `boot net` at the  ok prompt to reinstall.
- If not then you could set up another node as a jumpstart server. There is lots of documentation at oracle sites [Oracle Jumpstart Page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19056-01/sec.tk42/819-1402-10/jumpstart_servers_security_toolkit.html). A good blueprint also exists by John Howard and Alex Noordergraf. Be very careful if you take this root.
- If the OS is still installed, try booting from disk and having `vold` control the cd maybe it will close the tray.
- Get your driving gloves on.